# Xcode 14 Upgrade Causes Build Failure

Tags: xcode

Code that previously ran fine under Xcode 13.4 will no longer compile under Xcode 14. I get the error:

```
Property 'anchorPoint' with type "UserResizableViewAnchorPoint?' cannot override a property with type 'CGPoint'
Property cannot be declared public because its type uses and internal type
```

Could it be a Cocoa Pods issue? How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Well it seems pretty obvious. You need to track down the declaration of the "Property 'anchorPoint' with type "UserResizableViewAnchorPoint?'" and fix it. Only you can do this; we can't see your project.

Comment: Did you notice that the amount of actual code you've shown in your question is zero? Your question is totally unanswerable unless you show some code that elicits the issue.

Comment: Perhaps I'm the only one that had something like this break going from Xcode 13.4 to 14. However, if someone else did have the same problem and they were able to fix it then it is likely that they could help me with this despite my not posting any code per se. I don't understand why the downvote... I spent the better part of a day researching this, there is nothing unclear about a build failure, and it would be useful if I could compile code that would build previously.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me and I figured it out. Code was working fine on latest Xcode13 and presents this error on latest Xcode14. Not sure if it's the same issue you're having but hope it helps you isolate it.

This was the error I was seeing which matches yours:
[Xcode14 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbCx3.jpg)

Do you happen to be using a file that is dealing with resizing a view and manipulation of touches such as this which is defining a struct "UserResizableViewAnchorPoint"? And/Or using a variable called "anchorPoint" here?

```swift
    public struct UserResizableViewAnchorPoint {
        var adjustsX: CGFloat = 0
        var adjustsY: CGFloat = 0
        var adjustsH: CGFloat = 0
        var adjustsW: CGFloat = 0
    }
    
    public class UserResizableView: UIView {
        
        public weak var delegate: UserResizableViewDelegate?
        var borderView: GripViewBorderView?
        
        // Used to determine which components of the bounds we'll be modifying, based upon where the user's touch started.
        public var anchorPoint: UserResizableViewAnchorPoint?
```

The issue seems to be that `anchorPoint` is now used inside of CGPoint by Apple when it wasn't before. I was able to fix this by changing our variable simply to this so it wouldn't match:

```swift
    public var anchorPointer: UserResizableViewAnchorPoint?
```

Then changing every reference in that file where I was originally using `anchorPoint`. For example it was originally `anchorPoint` here and I updated it to `anchorPointer`:

```swift
   func isResizing() -> Bool {
            return (anchorPointer!.adjustsH != 0 || anchorPointer!.adjustsW != 0 || anchorPointer!.adjustsX != 0 || anchorPointer!.adjustsY != 0);
   }
```

You need to make sure to only update it where you're actually using your own variable though and not using anchorPoint within an existing function call or parameter because those should stay the same. You should just go through one by one where it was your variable and update it until you remove all the errors.